# Получить значение параметра js object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть объект:

```
var url = {
    first: "/url/to",
    second: "/url/to/2" 
}
```

Есть функция:

```
var GetUrl = function(type){
    return url[type]
}
```

И есть код:

```
<div data-ajax data-load="name, type"></div>
   var $block = jQuery('[data-ajax]');
   var $data = $block.data('load').split(',');
   jQuery.ajax({
    url: GetUrl($data[1]) + $data[0],
    type: "get",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (template) {
      StopSpinner(); // hide the spinner
      $block.html(template);
       },
     error: function (error) {
    $block.html("<p>Произошла ошибка при получении данных</p>");
   }
 });
```

И в итоге не удается получить значения объекта `url`. Почему? Ведь в функции `GetUrl` я передаю индекс что бы получить значение, но выходит андефаинд...

Comment: `GetUrl($data[1])` => `GetUrl(" type")`, `GetUrl($data[1]) + $data[0]` => `"undefinedname"`  - что Вы хотели бы получить в качестве значения `url`?

Comment: @Igor человек точно написал что хочет получить , надо или `first url` или `second url`

Comment: @Alex_01 - `data-load="name, type"` - это то, что у Вас в реальности в html?

Comment: @igor да, потом я сплитом его разбиваю. не хочу в 2 дата тега пихать

Comment: @Igor надо получить значение `first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var url = {
  first: "/url/to",
  second: "/url/to/2"
};

var GetUrl = function(type) {
  return url[type];
};

var $block = jQuery('[data-ajax]');
var $data = $block.data('load').split(',');
var url = GetUrl($data[1]);
console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-ajax data-load="name,first"></div>
```